# OTRS. Auto Responses. How to set them to be automatically marked as read (not starred)?

Tags: ticket-system

**Context:**

1. on OTRS, it is a good practice to set Auto Responses to customers, in order to make them feel supported outside of the working hours of the people who will read the Tickets;
2. however, the Auto Responses, on the OTRS Ticket Queue interface, begin their lives as "not read" (starred), just like a user-typed message that needs human attention;
3. this generates a lot of false positives for the people who have access to the OTRS Ticket Queue, because they think that there are replies from customers that need attention, just to discover, for example, it's an Auto Response alerting the customer that, if they don't reply in X days, the Ticker will be closed;
4. the only information that I could find online about Auto Responses being automatically set as "read" (not starred) was [someone asking exactly the same thing 9 years ago and getting a half-solution](https://otrs.otrs.narkive.com/WqttoVF8/auto-response-should-be-marked-as-read).

**Question:** how can I configure Auto Resposes to always be automatically marked as "read" (not starred) when looking at the Ticket Queue?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what version you use, but the same system configuration setting mentioned in the linked post is exactly what you asked for in all version I know.
Enable the system configuration "Ticket::NewArticleIgnoreSystemSender" and auto responses and all other system emails will be marked as "read" by default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).